# Trying to GET a job result works perfectly in Postman, but using AJAX in browser asks for app_code and app_id

Tags: jquery, ajax, postman, here-api

I'm trying to use the HERE job REST API to get my job results. I tested my GET request in Postman and it worked perfectly using my apiKey without using any extra headers (except Content-Type: application/octet-stream).

[image: Postman Request]

But when I try to try the same request using AJAX with jQuery, I get a 400 response telling me I need an app_id and app_code.
**My Code:**

```
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/octet-stream",
        type: 'GET',
        url: "https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/{JOB_ID}/result?apiKey={API_KEY}",
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

**The return header:**

```
{"error":"Bad Request","error_description":"The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id and app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at http://developer.here.com/myapps."}
```

Using this normal link does work when putting it into the URL bar in my browser.

Using a combination of the app id on the https://developer.here.com/projects/ page under REST and the apikey as the api_code doesn't work either. This tells me that it's an invalid pair.

I have no idea what credentials I should actually use now.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/dev_guide/topics/example-get-results.html) you have to use the `apikey` for authentication.
Please check this code for ajax which is working fine.

```
<html>
<button type="button" class="btn">Click me!</button>
<p class="text">Replace me!!</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.btn').click(function() {

  $('.text').text('loading . . ');

  $.ajax({
  type:"GET", 
 url:"https://batch.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/jobs/CxnGVvxLZeCjJnGRD0udKgLgeQzNa5xq/result?apiKey={apikey}",
    success: function(result) {
      $('.text').text(JSON.stringify(result));
      console.log(result);
    },

  });

  });
 </script>
 </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My issue was the contentType, removing that made it work. Thank you!